# Embedd Buttons with images and scrollbar on a frame using Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to make a on-button click event in a Tkinter window. I have a Tkinter Window on which there are buttons. Pressing one of those buttons,opens up a new Tkinter Window using Toplevel. This window would have a Scrollbar and some other buttons with images on it which can be vertically scrolled down. I could create the two functionalities separately,i.e, I could embedd a button with an image on a Tkinter window and use the Scrollbar but was unable to call the same function with the previous Tkinter window.

The code I am using is -

```
from Tkinter import * 
from ttk import *

class VerticalScrolledFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

        # create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it
        vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT, expand=FALSE)
        canvas = Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
        canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
        vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

        # reset the view
        canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = Frame(canvas)
        interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                                       anchor=NW)

        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                canvas.config(width=interior.winfo_reqwidth())
        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)

        def _configure_canvas(event):
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas
                canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=canvas.winfo_width())
        canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)


#if __name__ == "__main__":

class SampleApp(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #from Tkinter import *
        print "in constructor"
        import Tkinter
        import ImageTk

        import Image
        import cv2
        import numpy as np
        import cv2.cv as cv
        import math
        import tkFileDialog
        import tkMessageBox
        import Tkinter as tk
        root = Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        def Print():
            print "print function"

        self.frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(root)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.label = Label(text="Shrink the window to activate the scrollbar.")
        self.label.pack()

        compare_button_path = "compare-button.jpg"
        image_compare = Image.open(compare_button_path)
        image_compare.thumbnail((70,45))
        photo_compare = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_compare)
        button = tk.Button(self.frame, width=120, height=40, image=photo_compare,fg='black',bg='medium turquoise', activebackground='indian red',cursor="hand2",bd=6,relief=RAISED, compound=tk.LEFT, text="Compare",command = Print)
        button.image = photo_compare
        button.pack(side=LEFT)
        buttons = []
        for i in range(10):
            buttons.append(Button(self.frame.interior, text="Button " + str(i)))
            buttons[-1].pack()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

The above written function gives a pretty good result.

[image]

But how do I call this function on a button click from another Tkinter window? Changing the initial declaration of root to root = Tk() instead of  root = Tk.**init**(self, *args, **kwargs) throws a

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.
```

If I try to keep the function in some other file and import it into my original Tk file and create the object of that class on a button click, the second file gets automatically called during complilation of the original Tk file.
Can somebody please suggest a way out.

Comment: You wrote _"I could embedd a button with an image ... but could not integrate the same with the previous Tkinter window."_ What do you mean by "could not"? What prevented you from doing it? You wrote _"this function gives a pretty good result"_, which function? The code you posted has more than one function.

Comment: By could not integrate I meant, I was unable to make a window with a scrollbar which would have all buttons with images embedded on to them.

Comment: _Why_ were you unable? What prevented you from doing it? Did you get errors? Did the program crash? Did it silently not work? Did the buttons appear on the wrong window?

Comment: The buttons appeared with images but the scrollbars didnt function,i.e, I wanted that if I shrunk the window, I could scroll down to see the different buttons which is happening in the code I have posted, But when I add images and then shrink the window, the window becomes non scrollable.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're ask g. You claim to have problems with scrollbars in another window, but the code only shows one window, and you are asking how to call a function on a button click, and you show a revursion error which seems completely unrelated. It's very confusing.

Comment: I simply want to open a tkinter window with buttons and images, on a button click from another Tkinter window.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand your question, even after asking for clarification. You finally wrote in the comments of the question "I simply want to open a tkinter window with buttons and images, on a button click from another Tkinter window".

I don't see what's preventing you from doing that. The only thing I see wrong with your code is that you're simply not creating an instance of `Toplevel` (well, except for a confusing set of imports). Other than that, your code should work.

For example, if you modify your sample app to look something like this, you can open as many windows as you want:

```
class SampleApp(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        b = Button(self, text="Open a new window", command=self.open_new)
        b.pack()

    def open_new(self):
        top = Toplevel()
        self.frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(top)
        self.frame.pack()

        def Print():
            print "print function"

        button = Button(self.frame, text="Compare",command = Print)
        button.pack(side=LEFT)
        buttons = []
        for i in range(10):
            buttons.append(Button(self.frame.interior, text="Button " + str(i)))
            buttons[-1].pack()
```